# Adding a second supervisor

Tags: thesis

I would like to add a second supervisor to my phd thesis. I'm using the command:

```
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
\supervisor{Fernando Rubio Diez}
```

And referring it in my `.tex` document:

```
\emph{Director:} \\
\href{https://example.com}{\supname}
```

What is the best way to get another variable in order to refer a second supervisor?

I'm using this template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-east-london-masters-thesis-template/sgmtmhfbwqyp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Modify the title page: add a second row below Author and Supervisor to include the second supervisor. Each row consists of two minipages side by side.

(2) Add a new command to store and display the name of the second supervisor. `\director` was used here because `\supervisor` was already used for the first supervisor.

You did not specify where you want to place the title and the name of the second supervisor. In this example it is below the first supervisor. Maybe you want to have it centered?

[image: a]

The modifications added are marked.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex


\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)

\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage[round, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} % Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of numbers), remove 'numbers' 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphics}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=JungleGreen, colorlinks=true, citecolor=JungleGreen, linkcolor=black} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
%\SetWatermarkScale{2}
%\SetWatermarkColor{red}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.98}
\lstset{ language=R,% the language of the code
  numbers=left,% where to put the line-numbers
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},% the style that is used for the line-numbers
  stepnumber=1,  % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line
   % will be numbered
  numbersep=5pt,  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},% choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,% show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false, % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false, % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  frame=single, % adds a frame around the code
  rulecolor=\color{JungleGreen},% if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. commens (green here))
  tabsize=2,  % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=t, % sets the caption-position to top
  breaklines=true, % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=false, % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  title=\lstname, % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
 % also try caption instead of title
  keywordstyle=\color{RedViolet}, % keyword style
  commentstyle=\color{JungleGreen}, % comment style
  stringstyle=\color{orange}, % string literal style
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)}, % if you want to add a comment within your code
  morekeywords={*,...} % if you want to add more keywords to the set
} 
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0,0,128}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



%======================================================

\title{HMasters thesis template} % BUT you should use use " \title{\ttitle} " here instead to define the thesis title ! 
% \ttitle is defined in the file Thesis.cls 

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\setstretch{1.3} % Line spacing of 1.3

% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for one-sided printing
\fancyhead{} % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage} % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{} % Clears the left side page header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\rfoot{Add Name}
\lfoot{Add Student Number}
\pagestyle{fancy} % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % New command to make the lines in the title page

% PDF meta-data
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\ttitle}}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%%******************************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand*{\director}[2]{\def\dirname{#1}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\director{Fernando \textsc{Rubio Diez}} % You director's name - this is used in the title page
\supervisor{Name \textsc{Supervisor Surname}} % Your first supervisor's name - this is used in the title page
\authors{My Name \textsc{My Surname}} % Your name - this is used in the title page and abstract
%%*******************************************************

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\textsc{\LARGE \univname}\\[1.5cm] % University name
\textsc{\Large Masters Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle}\\[0.4cm] % Thesis title
\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line
 
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
\href{https://www.uel.ac.uk}{\authornames} \\% %Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
\href{https://www.uel.ac.uk}{\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link  
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
%*********************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\vspace*{1cm}\par
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} 
        %spare 
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} \large
            \emph{Director:}\\
            \href{https://www.uel.ac.uk}{\dirname} \\% Director name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link 
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]
%********************************************** 

\large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfilment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
\textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
%\groupname\\

\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name
\emph{Module Code:} ADD CODE\\
{\large \today}\\[1cm] % Date
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{./Images/UELlogo.png} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it
 
\vfill
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}



\end{document}
```