# Adding supervisor into MastersDoctoralThesis

Tags: thesis, environment-variables

I would like to add a second supervisor to my phd thesis. I'm using the Masters Doctoral Thesis template from: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl

I saw an answer ([Adding a second supervisor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662892/adding-a-second-supervisor)) to add a second supervisor but using `\director`. However, for my thesis I will need to add Supervisor's and not Director. What is the best way to modify `\supervisor` so it can be printed as plural and add a second name? And also, both supervisors name can get the `href` email available.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have a line `\emph{Supervisor:}`, just change it into `\emph{Supervisors:}`, and duplicate the next line, replacing `\supname` with the name of your second supervisor, and add \\ in between to separate the two names with a new line.

Comment: That's a problem, when templates come with little to no documentation. One way to do it is always to a) introduce new "variables" via `\newcommand`, and b) typesetting the title page yourself, i.e. copying and modifying the existing one. To do so, search for `\begin{titlepage}` environment in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#More_titlepage_examples (which is a good read, anyway).